# Third Party Live chat module for .NET (same as like Facebook)

Tags: asp.net, module, chat

I need to integrate private chat module in Asp.NET site.So, internal user can chat with other users.
I would be appreciate, if anyone can suggest that type of modules

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

See here about rolling your own it shouldnt be too hard with the building blocks given [ASP.NET Chat with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895101/asp-net-chat-with-wcf)

You can check out http://wcfchat.codeplex.com/ for a WCF implementation of chat.

Comment: Sure you can. You can just have straight up Ajax requests polling an HttpHandler for new messages and displaying them.

Comment: Implementing with ASP.Net MVC would be quite easy. Have a Chat controller and call a method on there using JQuery Ajax to get your new messages / post new chat messages. Have a backend DB working.